# How do] I call one method from a class to another class?

Tags: java

I need to know how to get these two methods:

```
public void setSerial(int ser)
{
    serialNumber = ser;
}
```

and

```
public double computeArea()
    {
        return width*length;
    }
```

into this a seperate class where this is located?

```
public void displayBoxes(){
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
        System.out.println(toString());
        System.out.println("The rectangle with the serial number " + ??? + " has the largest area: " + ???);
```

for an out put that is something like:

```
The rectangle of serial number 3 has the largest area: 9088.611
the question marks are where the numbers come into the print line.
```

Comment: Read this [Basic Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Should be something like that:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void setSerial(int ser)
    {
        serialNumber = ser;
    }

    public double computeArea()
    {
        return width*length;
    }
}
```

But that won't work:

```
public void displayBoxes(){
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
    System.out.println(toString());
    System.out.println("The rectangle with the serial number " + myClass.setSerial(12345) + " has the largest area: " + myClass.ComputerArea());
```

Because:
a. The setSerial() method is void. Doesn't return anything.
b. The ComputerArea() method doesn't take any arguments so there's no knowledge of what is width and what is length in the computerArea() method....

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your class where you want to call those methods an object of the class that has the methods, then create the object, assign it to a variable, and call the methods.

e.g.,

```
ClassA.java:

public ClassA {

   public void foo() {
     System.out.println("foo!!"):
   }
}
```

Now if you want ClassB to call this method in its constructor:

```
public ClassB {
   private ClassA myA = new ClassA();

   public ClassB() {
      myA.foo();
   }
}
```